# Input placeholder cutoff

Tags: html, css

My placeholder text for my input is being cut-off. Is there any way to show the text, other than increasing the length of the input box?

[image]

HTML is as follows:

```html
<section class="comment-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Try adding your own todosadsadasdsdaasdasdsaddsad!">
  <button>Clickez moi</buttoon>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  If there isn't enough room for something to display, it isn't going to display.  You need to make the input larger.

Answer (score 0):

you can't show all the text but you could add an ellipsis with this css.

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```